# Drawing YUV frames with OpenGL on mac

Tags: cocoa, opengl, ffmpeg

I'm decoding video with ffmpeg libraries and store decoded frames in array. Now i want to draw these frames on the screen with OpenGL. I googled and found that apple offers to use GL_APPLE_ycbcr_422 format for effective drawing. So i switched decoding frames in ffmpeg to PIX_FMT_YUYV422 format (packed YUV 4:2:2, 16bpp, Y0 Cb Y1 Cr) which seems to be an equivalent of GL_APPLE_ycbcr_422 in OpenGL. Now i'm trying to draw frames on surface with this code:

```
GLsizei width = 2, height = 2;
uint8_t data[8] = {128,200,123,10,5,13,54,180}; 
GLuint texture_name;

glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_ARB);
assert(glGetError() == GL_NO_ERROR);

glGenTextures (1,&texture_name);
assert(glGetError() == GL_NO_ERROR);

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_ARB, texture_name);
assert(glGetError() == GL_NO_ERROR);    

glTextureRangeAPPLE(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_ARB, width * height * 2, (void*)data);
assert(glGetError() == GL_NO_ERROR);

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_ARB, GL_TEXTURE_STORAGE_HINT_APPLE , GL_STORAGE_SHARED_APPLE);
assert(glGetError() == GL_NO_ERROR);

glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_CLIENT_STORAGE_APPLE, GL_TRUE);
assert(glGetError() == GL_NO_ERROR);

// not sure about code above    

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_ARB, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
assert(glGetError() == GL_NO_ERROR);

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_ARB, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
assert(glGetError() == GL_NO_ERROR);

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_ARB, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
assert(glGetError() == GL_NO_ERROR);

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_ARB, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
assert(glGetError() == GL_NO_ERROR);

glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ROW_LENGTH, 0);
assert(glGetError() == GL_NO_ERROR);    

// end

glViewport(0, 0,  width,height);
assert(glGetError() == GL_NO_ERROR);

glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);                    
assert(glGetError() == GL_NO_ERROR);

glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_ARB, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0,
             GL_YCBCR_422_APPLE,GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT_8_8_APPLE,
             (void*)data);
assert(glGetError() == GL_NO_ERROR);

glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_ARB, 0, 0, 0, width, height,
                GL_YCBCR_422_APPLE,GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT_8_8_APPLE,
                (void*)data);
assert(glGetError() == GL_NO_ERROR);    

glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION); 
glLoadIdentity();

glScalef(1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
glOrtho(0, width, 0, height, -1.0, 1.0);

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();

glBegin(GL_QUADS);

glVertex3f(0, 0, -1.0f);
glVertex3f(width, 0, -1.0f);
glVertex3f(width, height, -1.0f);
glVertex3f(0, height, -1.0f);

glEnd();
```

But i don't see correct frames. Instead i see corrupted  pictures of my display. So i understand that my using of OpenGL is not correct and maybe i don't understand some fundamental things.

Please, help to correct and to understand my mistakes. If i should RTFM please give me a link that will help me, because i didn't find any useful info.

Comment: Could you post your `glTexImage2D` call? The one that allocates storage for the texture.

Comment: Thanks for reply! If i understand, i do not need to call glTexImage2D because this function just converts from one pxl format to another. But if you are asking it, than probably i understood it wrong. Actually, i've used glTexImage2D call before with such parameters: glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_EXT, 0, GL_RGBA8, width, height, 0,
     GL_YCBCR_422_APPLE,GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT_8_8_APPLE,
     vp->bitmap)

Comment: You seemd to be right, i need to use glTexImage2D call before. Now i'm using it, but nothing changed

Comment: Update your post to include your new code.

Comment: Updated and added asserts for errors checking. Now i found that glTexImage2d is not working correct. Now i'm searching what is wrong...

Comment: It may be because you are using a sized internal format. Try just plain `GL_RGBA` rather than `GL_RGBA8`.

Comment: Changed to GL_RGBA as you said, but still getting GL_INVALID_OPERATION error.

Comment: @NicolBolas let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1574/discussion-between-oleg-and-nicol-bolas)

Comment: Now i'm trying to draw to draw one pixel. No errors, but pixel wasn't drawn!

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I use in one of my applications to set up a YUV 4:2:2 texture target for uploaded data from YUV frames pulled off of a CCD camera:

```
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_EXT);
glGenTextures(1, &textureName); 
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_EXT, textureName);
glTextureRangeAPPLE(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_EXT, videoImageSize.width * videoImageSize.height * 2, videoTexture);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_EXT, GL_TEXTURE_STORAGE_HINT_APPLE , GL_STORAGE_SHARED_APPLE);

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_EXT, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_EXT, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_EXT, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_EXT, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_REPLACE);

glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_EXT, 0, GL_RGBA, videoImageSize.width, videoImageSize.height, 0, GL_YCBCR_422_APPLE, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT_8_8_REV_APPLE, videoTexture);      
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_EXT, 0);
```

The actual upload to the texture is accomplished using the following:

```
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_EXT, textureName);
glTexSubImage2D (GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_EXT, 0, 0, 0, videoImageSize.width, videoImageSize.height, GL_YCBCR_422_APPLE, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT_8_8_REV_APPLE, videoTexture);
```

In the above, `videoTexture` is the memory location of the raw bytes from a captured YUV frame off of the camera.  I'm also using Apple's storage hints in the above to accelerate the upload, although I never could get the `GL_UNPACK_CLIENT_STORAGE_APPLE` optimization to speed things up further.

This was copied and pasted out of a working application, and the only real differences I see is my use of `GL_RGBA` instead of `GL_RGB` in the `getTexImage2D()` and the use of `GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT_8_8_REV_APPLE` instead of `GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT_8_8_APPLE`.  Both the ARB and EXT rectangle extensions resolve to the same thing on the Mac.

Comment: I tried your code for drawing several pixels and it seems it doesn't work too. Instead of pixels i see mesh-up of different pictures on my screen.

Comment: Changed the way of drawing... i see only white window now, not 4 pixel as i should

Comment: @Oleg - As I said, my code above is pasted verbatim from a functioning, tuned application, so if you're using this your problem is elsewhere.  Perhaps your texture doesn't have the right coordinates or isn't being drawn onscreen properly.  Have you tried this with a simple RGBA test texture, ignoring all the YUV stuff, just to verify that your actual drawing works right?

Comment: Thank you for reply. Actually, i found some mistakes in my code and fixed it. Now i can draw frames, but it seems it doesn't draw it correct. Instead of different pixels i see smth different (see below). It looks like i need to use non power of two extensions, but i'm not sure that problem is in that, because my texture is a power of two (16x16). Here is a code that i'm using http://pastebin.com/Pk6FkMnv. So, i'm generating a random texture, i put a breakpoint and checked that all values of *data* -variable are completely random.

Comment: And here is what i'm getting on the screen: http://cl.ly/2E3n2M0a0v3d0g2X2M2N http://cl.ly/1R3k29261i341K461m22 http://cl.ly/1m423r2F03422d3V3d45 . So i'm getting some mix of pixels, not their actual values. And it seems like it render it like it has problem with non-power-of two textures. But i don't understand why ? I'm using 16x16 picture...